# Python FTP-SSL / FTP-TLS: Verifying Public Certificate?

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, m2crypto, ftps, ftplib

I'm using Python 2.7.5 (not 3.X) and I need to verify a FTPS (FTP-TLS) public certificate. That is, I want to verify it against the standard certificate authority, not a custom key. (Similar to HTTPS.)

I see some options but I cannot get them to work:
The FTP_TLS() class doesn't seem to offer the ability to verify certificates, unless I'm mistaken:
`class ftplib.FTP_TLS([host[, user[, passwd[, acct[, keyfile[, certfile[, timeout]]]]]]])`

I've read into the `certifi` and also M2Crypto, but while I can connect and transfer using FTP/TLS, I can't seem to find a way to verify the certificate.

Also, I don't think I will be able to use the CURL libraries in this case :( Just a note.

Comment: Isn't this http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2008/10/14/ssl-in-python-26/ useful?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to make it into a possible answer: http://heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2008/10/14/ssl-in-python-26

Answer (score 0):

The resource referenced by [mcepl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18629023/1369668) is no longer available over http, but only using https.
https://heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2008/10/14/ssl-in-python-26

So much for 301 redirects.